# mysql - subqueries

Tags: mysql, sql, unpivot

I have this table

[image]

And I want to and can make it look like this

[image]

the query I used is this 
{

```
SELECT  Cat,Reg,Branch, Mnth, Qty
FROM
(
  SELECT Cat,Reg,Branch, 'Jan' Mnth, Jan Qty
  FROM BQV
  WHERE Jan > 0
  UNION ALL
  SELECT Cat,Reg,Branch, 'Feb', Feb
  FROM BQV

  UNION ALL
  SELECT Cat,Reg,Branch, 'Mar', Mar
  FROM BQV

UNION ALL
  SELECT Cat,Reg,Branch, 'Apr', Apr
  FROM BQV

UNION ALL
  SELECT Cat,Reg,Branch, 'May', May
  FROM BQV

UNION ALL
  SELECT Cat,Reg,Branch, 'Jun', Jun
  FROM BQV

UNION ALL
  SELECT Cat,Reg,Branch, 'Jul', Jul
  FROM BQV
  WHERE Feb > 0

  UNION ALL
  SELECT Cat,Reg,Branch, 'Aug', Aug
  FROM BQV

UNION ALL
  SELECT Cat,Reg,Branch, 'Sept', Sep
  FROM BQV

UNION ALL
  SELECT Cat,Reg,Branch, 'Oct', Octo
  FROM BQV

UNION ALL
  SELECT Cat,Reg,Branch, 'Nov', Nov
  FROM BQV

UNION ALL
  SELECT Cat,Reg,Branch, 'Dec', Dece
  FROM BQV

) QV
```

}

Can I achieve this via Views or a Stored procedure or anything ??
my MySQL ver is 5.5 and it can't have sub queries in a view and I cant upgrade my DB as I can't afford ANY loss or error whatsoever.

Comment: Instead of decreasing reputation, kindly speak up, as simply decreasing reputation doesn't help a bit. At least comment if u can help in anyway.

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images (or links to images.)

Comment: Does MySQL really need a sub-query to do a UNION ALL? Can't you simply do UNION ALL without the sub-query?

Comment: Being a dev, and nothing close to a DBA, I can only ask you if its possible to do what I am trying to do, and if yes, then how.

Comment: create view viewname as select ... union all ... union all ...

Comment: if I give u all queries (table creation and the working result), can u try to get it via view ??

Comment: Table creation and  row insertion -->  create table BQV (Cat varchar(50) , Reg VARCHAR(50), Branch VARCHAR(50), Jan varchar(50),Feb VARCHAR(50),Mar VARCHAR(50),Apr VARCHAR(50),May VARCHAR(50),Jun VARCHAR(50),Jul VARCHAR(50),Aug VARCHAR(50),Sep VARCHAR(50),Octo VARCHAR(50),Nov VARCHAR(50),Dece VARCHAR(50));
 insert into BQV values ('WASHER','WEST','Gujarat', 1321,45,2573,16557,2364,6463,6768,4464,1346,94566,34193,396);

Comment: My working query to display my table as expected -->SELECT  Cat,Reg,Branch, Mnth, Qty FROM( SELECT Cat,Reg,Branch, 'Jan' Mnth, Jan Qty FROM BQV UNION ALL SELECT Cat,Reg,Branch, 'Feb', Feb FROM BQ  UNION ALL SELECT Cat,Reg,Branch, 'Mar',Mar FROM BQV UNION ALL SELECT Cat,Reg,Branch, 'Apr', Apr FROM BQV UNION ALL SELECT Cat,Reg,Branch, 'May', May FROM BQV UNION ALL SELECT Cat,Reg,Branch, 'Jun', Jun FROM BQV UNION ALL SELECT Cat,Reg,Branch, 'Jul', Jul FROM BQV UNION ALL SELECT Cat,Reg,Branch, 'Aug', Aug FROM BQV UNION ALL SELECT Cat,Reg,Branch, 'Sept', Sep FROM BQV
)QV;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following VIEW does what I needed perfectly.

CREATE VIEW `scheme-test`.`trybqv1` 
   AS

SELECT Cat,Reg,Branch, 'Jan' Mnth,Jan Qty
FROM BQV A
 UNION ALL
SELECT Cat,Reg,Branch, 'Feb', Feb
FROM BQV

UNION ALL
SELECT Cat,Reg,Branch, 'Mar', Mar
FROM BQV

UNION ALL
SELECT Cat,Reg,Branch, 'Apr', Apr
FROM BQV

UNION ALL
SELECT Cat,Reg,Branch, 'May', May
FROM BQV

UNION ALL
SELECT Cat,Reg,Branch, 'Jun', Jun
FROM BQV

UNION ALL
SELECT Cat,Reg,Branch, 'Jul', Jul
FROM BQV

UNION ALL
SELECT Cat,Reg,Branch, 'Aug', Aug
FROM BQV

UNION ALL
SELECT Cat,Reg,Branch, 'Sept', Sep
FROM BQV

UNION ALL
SELECT Cat,Reg,Branch, 'Oct', Octo
FROM BQV

UNION ALL
SELECT Cat,Reg,Branch, 'Nov', Nov
FROM BQV

UNION ALL
SELECT Cat,Reg,Branch, 'Dec', Dece
FROM BQV

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a *Derived Table* (which is wronlgy named *Subquery* by MySQL), simply remove it:

```
CREATE VIEW foo AS
SELECT Cat,Reg,Branch, 'Jan' AS Mnth, Jan AS Qty
FROM BQV
WHERE Jan > 0

UNION ALL
SELECT Cat,Reg,Branch, 'Feb', Feb
FROM BQV

UNION ALL
SELECT Cat,Reg,Branch, 'Mar', Mar
FROM BQV

UNION ALL
SELECT Cat,Reg,Branch, 'Apr', Apr
FROM BQV

UNION ALL
SELECT Cat,Reg,Branch, 'May', May
FROM BQV

UNION ALL
SELECT Cat,Reg,Branch, 'Jun', Jun
FROM BQV

UNION ALL
SELECT Cat,Reg,Branch, 'Jul', Jul
FROM BQV
WHERE Feb > 0

UNION ALL
SELECT Cat,Reg,Branch, 'Aug', Aug
FROM BQV

UNION ALL
SELECT Cat,Reg,Branch, 'Sept', Sep
FROM BQV

UNION ALL
SELECT Cat,Reg,Branch, 'Oct', Octo
FROM BQV

UNION ALL
SELECT Cat,Reg,Branch, 'Nov', Nov
FROM BQV

UNION ALL
SELECT Cat,Reg,Branch, 'Dec', Dece
FROM BQV
```

Another solution is based on a `CROSS JOIN` to a 2nd table storing the months names 'Jan' to 'Dec':

```
create table months ( mnth char(3));
insert into months values ('Jan'),('Feb'),...

select Cat,Reg,Branch, months.mnth, 
   case mnth 
     when 'Jan' then Jan
     when 'Feb' then Feb
     ...
     when 'Dec' then Dece
   end
from BQV CROSS JOIN months
```